# Footer at bottom of page for responsive screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I want footer to stick at bottom of page and 43 pixels above bottom boundary. and If screen resolution changed, it should not overlap the content. Below css is for 1920 dimension. I want it to be responsive for other dimensions too.

I added ***position: absolute*** and ***bottom:0*** but it places the footer at bottom. and it overlaps the content if resolution changed.

***margin-top: auto*** also not working.

**Html**

```
<div className="col-md-12 p-0 login-page">
   <div className="main-container">
     <div className="wrapLoginPage">
        <div className="content">

          <div className="img-logo">
            <img src={GooglerLogo} alt="Logo" height={58} width={95} />
          </div>
          <div  className="img-caption">
            MI jjfkjd  fdnfjdjf fjndjfdjf dfjdjfjdnfjdfdf
          </div>

          // .login-div (css)
          {this._renderLoginForm()}

          <div className="footer-container">
            <div className="footer-img">
                <img src={AppleLogo} alt="Apple Logo" height={48} width={48}/>
            </div>
            <div className="footer-text">
              Lorem ipsum footr content dfd dfdgfdgfd
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

          <div className="left-container">
              {/* <img src={SampleImg} alt="Sample" height={840} width={1350} /> */}
          </div>

     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
// Login Page
@import "../mixins.scss";

.login-page {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;

  .main-container {
    width: 100%;  
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .left-container {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(100% - 490px);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f7f7fc 60%, #F2D8FF 40%);
    position: relative;
  }

  .wrapLoginPage {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }

  .content {
    width: 490px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 101px 50px 43px 44px;
  }

  .img-logo {
    padding-bottom: 18px;
  }
  .img-caption {
    color: #1C2C42;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-bottom: 113px;
  }

  
  .login-div {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
 

  .footer-container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    
    .footer-text {
      width: 297px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 18px;
      color: #575E6B;
      padding-left: 12px;
    }
  }
}
```

[This is the screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgezK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to set a specific height for your "footer-container", let's asume like 30vh height.
- You use the footer height we just add (30vh) as padding-bottom for the main-container + set box-sizing to => "border-box"
  Box-sizing allows the padding of the selected element to be "part of" the height (100vh)
- Maybe you will need to prevend some wrapping or overflow on small screen, even if that's not super pretty, i sould add an overflow:auto to footer-container.

So the result CSS :

```
// Login Page
@import "../mixins.scss";

.login-page {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;

.main-container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.left-container {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(100% - 490px);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f7f7fc 60%, #F2D8FF 40%);
    position: relative;
}

.wrapLoginPage {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.content {
    width: 490px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 101px 50px 30vh 44px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-logo {
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}
.img-caption {
    color: #1C2C42;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-bottom: 113px;
}


.login-div {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}


.footer-container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

.footer-text {
    width: 297px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #575E6B;
    padding-left: 12px;
    height: 30vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
}
}
```

Hope I have well understood what you are looking for :)

Comment: Well it works.. I need to tweak bit for final change. Thanks